# Single Method to create Sorted List<T> where T : Base Class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, instantiation, abstraction

I have an interface for items which are Votable: (Like StackExchange, Reddit, etc...)

```
// Irrelevant properties left out (Creator, Upvotes, Downvotes, etc)
internal interface IVotable
{
    double HotScore { get; set; }
    double VoteTotal { get; set; }
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have a concrete base class which extends this interface and defines a constructor to populate the default properties:

```
internal class SCO : IVotable
{
    public double HotScore { get; set; }
    public double VoteTotal { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public SCO(SPListItem item, List<Vote> votes)
    {
        VoteTotal = UpVotes - DownVotes;
        HotScore = Calculation.HotScore(Convert.ToInt32(UpVotes), Convert.ToInt32(DownVotes), Convert.ToDateTime(item["Created"]));
        CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item["Created"]);
    }
```

Here is an example of a class in use which extends this base class and it's constructor:

```
class Post : SCO
{
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public Uri Link { get; set; }

    public Post(SPListItem item, List<Vote> votes)
        : base(item, votes)
    {
        Summary = (string) item["Summary"];
        Link = new UriBuilder((string) item["Link"]).Uri;
    }
}
```

Over 90% of the time, I'm returning sorted collections of the classes for rendering on a page.

I would like to have a generic method of some kind that takes in a collection of DataBase Items, a List of Votes to match with the Items, creates a List, and then sorts that list based on a passed ENUM that defines how to sort.

I've tried a few approaches, many of them based on previous posts. I'm not sure if I'm approaching this in the right way. While the solutions do work, I see a lot of Boxing, or Reflection, or some kind of (possibly major) sacrifice in performance for readability, or ease of use.

What is the best way to Create a Sorted List of objects that can be used in any subsequent child class as long as that class extends the base class?

**Previous Approach that is working:**

[Create a List of <T> from a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117980/create-a-list-of-t-from-a-base-class/12118019#12118019)

A Generic List of `<T>` embedded in the Base Class which extends `Activator.CreateInstance` using reflection to return the list:

```
public static List<T> SortedCollection<T>(SPListItemCollection items, ListSortType sortType, List<Vote> votes) where T : SCO
```

**Request for Sample of use:**

```
    static public List<Post> Get100MostRecentPosts(ListSortType sortType)
    {
        var targetList = CoreLists.SystemAccount.Posts();
        var query = new SPQuery
                        {
                            Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Created\" Ascending=\"False\" /></OrderBy>",
                            RowLimit = 100
                        };
        var listItems = targetList.GetItems(query);
        var votes = GetVotesForPosts(listItems);
        return Post.SortedCollection<Post>(listItems, sortType, votes);
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx).

Comment: That was fast! Might be, but that only solves sorting without instantiation.

Comment: Can't you just get your collection first, and then apply `OrderBy` to it?  You're gonna need to sort it anyhow.  Just add the `OrderBy` to whatever code is currently returning the unsorted collection.

Comment: I can, but then I'm writing an InstantiateCollection method for every sub class, each looking almost identical. Because each sub class creates and extends the constructor, a generic object creation loop will work. See the link at the bottom for "Create a List<T> from a base class"

Comment: Yes, but will you sort it the same way in each and every subclass?  The OrderBy clause allows you to override this behavior, specifying a different sorting for each.  If I read you correctly, it will add about five lines of code to each class (including the braces).

Comment: `OrderBy` is great, but sometimes the old 2.0 way of insisting classes implement `IComparable<T>` works even better (or for that matter, the two play nicely together).

Comment: Could you post a small example showing how you intend to use the sorted list?  I'm just trying to get a feel for the API you're going for.